# How to enter a random 6 digit number with hyphen in between for a text box in selenium web driver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have scenario where in an text box i need to enter value like : 234-89. Numbers need to randomly generated each time i run the test, "-" should be added after 3 numbers and rest two numbers should also be random. How can i do it ?

Comment: What keeps you from entering the numbers? Can you use dice to make them random? What text box are you referring to? I have no idea how an answer to your question might look like.

Answer (score 1):

Generate two random numbers, the first one 3 digits, the second one 2 digits. Then concatenate both variables with a hyphen in between them.

If you need help generating random numbers, see this link  https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-generate-random-numbers-in-java

Answer (score 0):

there are many options to generate random numbers in Java

> Option -1

JavaFaker's fake data classes in java

or Option 2-

```
import java.util.Random; 


     Random rand = new Random(); 

    // Generate 3digit random integers in range 0 to 999 
    int rand1 = rand.nextInt(1000); 
    // Generate 2digit random integers in range 0 to 99 
    int rand2 = rand.nextInt(100); 
    String textfortexbox=Integer.toString(rand1)+"-"+Integer.toString(rand2);
```

> Output 999-99